# DFCC (discrete finite chain condition )

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ has the DFCC (discrete  finite chain condition ) provided every discrete family of nonempty open sets is finite. [(see A survey on star covering propertiesMV Matveev - Topology Atlas, preprint, 1998)](http://at.yorku.ca/v/a/a/a/19.htm)

Does the discrete family of nonempty open sets mean that every point $x \in X $ has a nbhd that intersects at most one set of the given family?

However, in the proof of the Theorem 14 in the charpter 2, why he said if the sequence $S=\{U_n:n\in \omega\}$ is not DFCC, then there exists $x \in X$ is an accumulation point for $S$, each nbhd of $x$ meets infinitely many $U_n$'s? Why is "infinitely"? This is puzzling me.

Thanks for any help:)

Answer (score 1):

> Does the discrete family of nonempty open sets mean that every point $x\in X$ has a nbhd that intersects at most one set of the given family?

Accordingly to Engelking’s “General topology”, yes.

> Why is "infinitely"?

It seems that there is an error in the proof exposition.  The contradiction is already implied from the fact that a neighborhood $V$ intersects two different $U_n$-s. Therefore no such neighborhood of $x$ can exist and the sequence $s$ should be discrete.

See, for instance, the proof of Theorem 2.1.7 (that each DFCC space is 2-starcompact) in "[Star-covering properties](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/bill.roscoe/publications/40.pdf)" by E.K. van Douwen, G.M. Reed, A.W. Roscoe, and I.J. Tree.